# How to check to see that a set of variables is not null before continuing

Tags: java, validation, variables

I have a class that extends org.apache.ant.tools.Task.  This class has 5 variables which are set via public setters:

```
private String server;
private String username;
private String password;
private String appname;
private String version;
private String file;
```

And then there is a public execute() method which is invoked by ant:

```
public void execute() throws BuildException {
    checkArgs()
    ... // my execute code goes here
}
```

Before execute runs, I want to check that none of my required variables are null and, if so, throw a BuildException() describing the problem, so the user back in ant has some idea what's wrong:

```
private void checkArgs() {
    if (server == null) {
        throw new BuildException("server cannot be null.");
    }

    if (username == null) {
        throw new BuildException("username cannot be null.");
    }

    if (password == null) {
        throw new BuildException("password cannot be null.");
    }

    if (file == null) {
        throw new BuildException("file cannot be null.");
    }

    if (version == null) {
        throw new BuildException("version cannot be null.");
    }
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to do this?  I hate the repeated use of `if` like this and if there's a more efficient way to do it, I'd love to see it.  I can just imagine how it would look if I had, say, 20 different variables I need to check before execute() can run.

What is a good method for validating large numbers of different variables as a precursor continuing code execution or throwing a useful error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store the args in a `HashMap<String, String> argMap`, mapping the argument names to their values. Adjust your getters/setters accordingly. Then:

```
for (String key : argMap.keySet()) {
    if (argMap.get(key) == null) {
        throw new BuildException(key + " cannot be null.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement could be achieved by using *asserts*:

```
public void execute()
throws BuildException
{
    assert server!=null : "server cannot be null";
    assert version!=null : "version cannot be null";
    ...
}
```

... And then running ant always with the `-ea` JVM option (Enable Asserts).

Yes, you still have to code one assert by variable, but at least it would be just one line per one of them.

Comment: This is a cool idea and I like it, but I won't be able to require that everyone use the -ea options when running ant.  It's done internally within Eclipse as part of the Android build and I bet most people don't have this enabled.  Good to know though!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to add the Map (as in Claudiu answer), you could use reflection:

```
private void checkArgs() throws BuildException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field: this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
         if (field.get(this) == null) {
             throw new BuildException(field.getName() + " cannot be null.");
         }
    }
}
```

but pay attention: the getDeclaredFields() will return all the fields of the class (either private, protected or public).