# A utility method representing, "Both not null and not equal" in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
String str = "abc";
```

Comparing this string variable like the following.

```
if(str.equals("abc")) {}
```

In case `str` is `null`, it will cause a `java.lang.NullPointerException` to be thrown as obvious.

To avoid that, an additional null check may be enforced. Such as,

```
if(str != null && str.equals("abc")) {}
```

I find it plain ugly. Better could be rewritten as follows.

```
if("abc".equals(str)) {}
```

This will never throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException` even though `str` is `null`. Besides, object equals `null` is never true.

---

The last case however, cannot be used, when the conditional expression is inverted like so,

```
if(!"abc".equals(str)) {
    System.out.println(str.length());
}
```

This will cause a `java.lang.NullPointerException` inside the `if` block, if `str` is `null`.

Can this somehow be avoided without rewriting the conditional statement like the following?

```
if(str != null && !"abc".equals(str)) {}
```

This is plain ugly and unreadable.

---

<sub>Although the example uses a `String` object, it may be a more complex object.</sub>

Comment: You have to add a condition to the print statement : `System.out.println(str != null ? str.length() : 0);`

Comment: write a static method which handles null silently...

Comment: if possible use apache commons [`StringUtils.isEmpty()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)) that makes code readable as well

Comment: could you explain why you think condition `(str != null && !"abc".equals(str))` is ugly?

Comment: @user902383 : Despite the fact that this is a toy example, the code will get uglier at long run in big applications, if there are so many such conditional checks.

Comment: Avoid `str` being `null` in the first place…

Comment: @Holger : It is not always possible. For example, if there is a null foreign key in the database (`ON DELETE SET NULL`), a null check is unavoidable on the JPA/ORM side. I however, excluded that part from this question.

Comment: It still should be sorted out way before doing any string comparisons…

Comment: @Tiny if you have too many conditions you could create utility method to deal with them or disallow to use null, and use null object pattern instead

Comment: I like `commons-lang`'s `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(string)` method, personally. If you don't want to include the lib, you can just make your own.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce : I also use that library extensively :). Besides that I see, when objects to be compared are other than a String, an additional condition is always necessary such as `if(object1 != null && object1.equals(object2)) {...}`. (A client can supply a `User` object with optional field values of `Country`, `State` and `City` all three set to `null` in `User`. In this case, it is absolutely not the client's responsibility to fight against a `null` value. It is however, the upper service layer's responsibility to adequately handle a `java.lang.NullPointerException` whenever necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short : There is simply no library method doing this which I know of. This `if(str != null && !"abc".equals(str)) {}` actually requires that both the objects to be compared are not `null` and not equal to each other.

A static utility method performing this task is sufficient to deal with.

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if and only if both the arguments (objects) are
 * <b>not</b> {@code null} and are not equal to each other and {@code false}
 * otherwise.
 *
 * @param a an object.
 * @param b an object to be compared with {@code a} for equality.
 * @return {@code true} if both the arguments (objects) are <b>not</b> {@code null}
 * and not equal to each other.
 */
public static boolean notEquals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b || a == null || b == null) ? false : !a.equals(b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative could be to use the Java 8 optional wrapper

```
Optional<Customer> optional = findCustomer();

if (optional.isPresent()) {
Customer customer = maybeCustomer.get();
    ... use customer ...
}
else {
    ... deal with absence case ...
}
```

source: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-how-use-it

Comment: Side note: if you are not yet on java 7, have a look at Guava's Optional.

Comment: You should make your example closer to the use case of the question, e.g. `Optional.ofNullable(oldAPIreturningNullable).filter(s -> !s.equals("abc)).ifPresent( s->intendedAction);`…

Comment: This is only helpful/useful, when developers inadvertently forget to do null checks. It also requires conditional checks. What is the benefit of doing this, `Fruit fruit = new Fruit(); Optional<Fruit>optional = Optional.of(fruit); if(optional.isPresent()) {System.out.println("present");}` than simply doing this `if(fruit != null) {System.out.println("present");}`? In both the cases, a test condition is required. Besides, `Optional.of(fruit)` itself throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, if `fruit` itself is `null` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for `null` at some point if you want to use `str`. There is simply no way around it. You can wrap this check into a additional utility function or something like this, but in the end you will not get around the additional check.

If you are a friend of using loads of additional libraries you could use [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#length(java.lang.String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#length(java.lang.String)). That does just what you want, maybe you got a library like that present in your application anyway. The apache one is only a example. There are surely others around that do similar things.

If you want to remove the `null` check all together maybe the better question is: Why can `str` be `null` and it is possible to prevent it being `null` by not accepting this value from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to avoid nulls is using an `assert`: Look at this answer in another similar question:

[How to check to see that a set of variables is not null before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525891/how-to-check-to-see-that-a-set-of-variables-is-not-null-before-continuing/31526270#31526270)