# Prevent Hibernate from deleting orphaned entities while merging an entity having entity associations with orphanRemoval set to true

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orphan, orphaned-objects

Taking a very simple example of one-to-many relationship (country `->` state).

Country (inverse side) :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<StateTable> stateTableList=new ArrayList<StateTable>(0);
```

StateTable (owning side) :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Country country;
```

The method attempting to update a supplied (detached) `StateTable` entity within an active database transaction (JTA or resource local) :

```
public StateTable update(StateTable stateTable) {

    // Getting the original state entity from the database.
    StateTable oldState = entityManager.find(StateTable.class, stateTable.getStateId());
    // Get hold of the original country (with countryId = 67, for example).
    Country oldCountry = oldState.getCountry();
    // Getting a new country entity (with countryId = 68) supplied by the client application which is responsible for modifying the StateTable entity.
    // Country has been changed from 67 to 68 in the StateTable entity using for example, a drop-down list.
    Country newCountry = entityManager.find(Country.class, stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId());
    // Attaching a managed instance to StateTable.
    stateTable.setCountry(newCountry);

    // Check whether the supplied country and the original country entities are equal.
    // (Both not null and not equal - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31761967/1391249)
    if (ObjectUtils.notEquals(newCountry, oldCountry)) {
        // Remove the state entity from the inverse collection held by the original country entity.
        oldCountry.remove(oldState);
        // Add the state entity to the inverse collection held by the newly supplied country entity
        newCountry.add(stateTable);
    }

    return entityManager.merge(stateTable);
}
```

It should be noted that `orphanRemoval` is set to `true`. The `StateTable` entity is supplied by a client application which is interested in changing the entity association `Country` (`countryId = 67`) in `StateTable` to something else (`countryId = 68`) (thus on the inverse side in JPA, migrating a child entity from its parent (collection) to another parent (collection) which `orphanRemoval=true` will in turn oppose).

The Hibernate provider issues a `DELETE` DML statement causing the row corresponding to the `StateTable` entity to be removed from the underlying database table.

Despite the fact that `orphanRemoval` is set to `true`, I expect Hibernate to issue a regular`UPDATE` DML statement causing the effect of `orphanRemoval` to be suspended in its entirely because the relationship link is migrated (not simply deleted).

EclipseLink does exactly that job. It issues an `UPDATE` statement in the scenario given (having the same relationship with `orphanRemoval` set to `true`).

Which one is behaving according to the specification? Is it possible to make Hibernate issue an `UPDATE` statement in this case other than removing `orphanRemoval` from the inverse side?

---

<sub>This is only an attempt to make a bidirectional relationship more consistent on both the sides.</sub>

<sub>The defensive link management methods namely `add()` and `remove()` used in the above snippet, if necessary, are defined in the `Country` entity as follows.</sub>

```
public void add(StateTable stateTable) {
    List<StateTable> newStateTableList = getStateTableList();

    if (!newStateTableList.contains(stateTable)) {
        newStateTableList.add(stateTable);
    }

    if (stateTable.getCountry() != this) {
        stateTable.setCountry(this);
    }
}

public void remove(StateTable stateTable) {
    List<StateTable> newStateTableList = getStateTableList();

    if (newStateTableList.contains(stateTable)) {
        newStateTableList.remove(stateTable);
    }
}
```

---

**Update :**

Hibernate can only issue an expected `UPDATE` DML statement, if the code given is modified in the following way.

```
public StateTable update(StateTable stateTable) {
    StateTable oldState = entityManager.find(StateTable.class, stateTable.getStateId());
    Country oldCountry = oldState.getCountry();
    // DELETE is issued, if getReference() is replaced by find().
    Country newCountry = entityManager.getReference(Country.class, stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId());

    // The following line is never expected as Country is already retrieved 
    // and assigned to oldCountry above.
    // Thus, oldState.getCountry() is no longer an uninitialized proxy.
    oldState.getCountry().hashCode(); // DELETE is issued, if removed.
    stateTable.setCountry(newCountry);

    if (ObjectUtils.notEquals(newCountry, oldCountry)) {
        oldCountry.remove(oldState);
        newCountry.add(stateTable);
    }

    return entityManager.merge(stateTable);
}
```

Observe the following two lines in the newer version of the code.

```
// Previously it was EntityManager#find()
Country newCountry = entityManager.getReference(Country.class, stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId());
// Previously it was absent.
oldState.getCountry().hashCode();
```

If either the last line is absent or `EntityManager#getReference()` is replaced by `EntityManager#find()`, then a `DELETE` DML statement is unexpectedly issued.

So, what is going on here? Especially, I emphasize portability. Not porting this kind of **basic** functionality across different JPA providers defeats the use of ORM frameworks severely.

<sub>I understand the basic difference between `EntityManager#getReference()` and `EntityManager#find()`.</sub>

Comment: Just a thought but does it make any difference if you do the add before the remove?

Comment: Changing the order of those two lines does not make any difference. I have checked such possibilities beforehand :)

Comment: Looks like a Hibernate bug. Just a guess, explicitly merge the new country and then old country before the state. If necessary invoke flush in between.

Comment: @BalusC : I have tried merging `newCountry` first and then `oldCountry` and vice versa prior to merging `stateTable`. It threw an exception : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [entity.StateTable#32] are being merged. Managed: [entity.StateTable[stateId=32]]; Detached: [entity.StateTable[stateId=32]]`. I will remove `orphanRemoval` from everywhere, if no solution is ever likely to exist.

Comment: Hmm, why `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`?  Shouldn't you be avoiding `CascadeType.REMOVE` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis : No difference avoiding `CascadeType.REMOVE` from the inverse side.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, let's change your original code to a simpler form :

```
StateTable oldState = entityManager.find(StateTable.class, stateTable.getStateId());
Country oldCountry = oldState.getCountry();
oldState.getCountry().hashCode(); // DELETE is issued, if removed.

Country newCountry = entityManager.find(Country.class, stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId());
stateTable.setCountry(newCountry);

if (ObjectUtils.notEquals(newCountry, oldCountry)) {
    oldCountry.remove(oldState);
    newCountry.add(stateTable);
}

entityManager.merge(stateTable);
```

Notice that I only added `oldState.getCountry().hashCode()` in the third line. Now you can reproduce your issue by removing this line only.

Before we explain what's going on here, first some excerpts from the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

Section **3.2.4**:

> The semantics of the flush operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
>   - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value
>       cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y

Section **3.2.2**:

> The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - **If X is a removed entity, it becomes managed.**

[`orphanRemoval` JPA javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval--):

> (Optional) Whether to **apply the remove operation** to entities that
>   have been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove
>   operation to those entities.

As we can see, `orphanRemoval` is defined in terms of `remove` operation, so all the rules that apply for `remove` **must** apply for `orphanRemoval` as well.

Secondly, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861675/4754790), the order of updates executed by Hibernate is the order in which entities are loaded in the persistence context. To be more precise, updating an entity means synchronizing its current state (dirty check) with the database and cascading the `PERSIST` operation to its associations.

Now, this is what's happening in your case. At the end of the transaction Hibernate synchronizes the persistence context with the database. We have two scenarios:

1. When the extra line (`hashCode`) is present :

   1. Hibernate synchronizes `oldCountry` with the DB. It does it before handling `newCountry`, because `oldCountry` was loaded first (proxy initialization forced by calling `hashCode`).
   2. Hibernate sees that a `StateTable` instance has been removed from the `oldCountry`'s collection, thus marking the `StateTable` instance as removed.
   3. Hibernate synchronizes `newCountry` with the DB. The `PERSIST` operation cascades to the `stateTableList` which now contains the removed `StateTable` entity instance.
   4. The removed `StateTable` instance is now managed again (3.2.2 section of JPA specification quoted above).
2. When the extra line (`hashCode`) is absent :

   1. Hibernate synchronizes `newCountry` with the DB. It does it before handling `oldCountry`, because `newCountry` was loaded first (with `entityManager.find`).
   2. Hibernate synchronizes `oldCountry` with the DB.
   3. Hibernate sees that a `StateTable` instance has been removed from the `oldCountry`'s collection, thus marking the `StateTable` instance as removed.
   4. The removal of the `StateTable` instance is synchronized with the database.

The order of updates also explains your findings in which you basically forced `oldCountry` proxy initialization to happen before loading `newCountry` from the DB.

So, is this according to the JPA specification? Obviously yes, no JPA spec rule is broken.

Why is this not portable?

JPA specification (like any other specification after all) gives freedom to the providers to define many details not covered by the spec.

Also, that depends on your view of the 'portability'. The `orphanRemoval` feature and any other JPA features are portable when it comes to their formal definitions. However, it depends on how you use them in combination with the specifics of your JPA provider.

By the way, section **2.9** of the spec recommends (but does not clearly define) for the `orphanRemoval`:

> Portable applications must otherwise not depend upon a specific order
>   of removal, and must not reassign an entity that has been orphaned to
>   another relationship or otherwise attempt to persist it.

But this is just an example of vague or not-well-defined recommendations in the spec, because persisting of removed entities is allowed by other statements in the specification.

Comment: Now going a bit further : Doing `Country oldCountry = entityManager.find(Country.class, oldState.getCountry().getCountryId());` eliminates the need for adding this line `oldState.getCountry().hashCode();` but to me, `EntityManager#find()` should also not be needed. This `Country oldCountry = oldState.getCountry();` should fetch a fully qualified entity as the method runs within an active JTA transaction. `oldState.getCountry()` is not an uninitialized proxy as returned by `EntityManager#getReference()` which cannot be loaded unless explicitly loaded by doing `oldState.getCountry().hashCode();`

Comment: Perhaps, it might work with `<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>` but I am not interested in using it as it cannot be used without serious caution.

Comment: @Tiny `oldState.getCountry()` returns an uninitialized proxy (the association is lazy). `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` has nothing to do with your issue (will neither help nor harm).

Comment: @Tiny Suppose that you have two `stateTable` detached instances. Which one should `oldState.getCountry()` pick to load the state from, even if the persistence engine were aware of the existence of detached instances? :)

Comment: To other potential readers : Changing attributes of `cascade` from any of the sides will throw appropriate exceptions as obvious like `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`. Merging multiple entities of the same type having the same entity associations within the same transaction will throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.ex.Entity#1] are being merged. Managed: [com.ex.Entity[entityId=1]]; Detached: [com.ex.Entity[entityId=1]]` (EclipseLink does not do it). The code will then need to be changed accordingly

Comment: The solution to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity are being merged` will be `<property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>` available in Hibernate 4.3.6 or above. Or removing `CascadeType.MERGE` from the owning side.

Answer (score 4):

As soon as your referenced entity can be used in other parents, it gets complicated anyway. To really make it clean, the ORM had to search in the database for any other usages of the removed entity before deleting it (persistent garbage collection). This is time consuming and therefore not really useful and therefore not implemented in Hibernate.

Delete orphans only works if your child is used for a single parent and never reused somewhere else. You may even get an exception when trying to reuse it to better detect the misuse of this feature.

Decide whether you want to keep delete orphans or not. If you want to keep it, you need to create a new child for the new parent instead of moving it.

If you abandon delete orphans, you have to delete the children yourself as soon as they are not referenced anymore.

Comment: Gosh! This is a portability issue for this kind of rudimentary functionality. It should have clearly been stated in the JPA specification.

Comment: As I tried to point out: it is not as rudimentary as soon as you start to think about possible scenarios where not everything is in memory. Anyway, there is a chance that I'm wrong, because I know it from NHibernate. I just assumed that it is the same there.